# set aside vaccine for long-term-care facilities

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "set aside vaccine for long-term-care facilities" mean "should use vaccine **exclusively** for long-term-care facilities"?

I searched "set aside something for" and only got what is "set aside":"Separate and reserve for a special purpose, as in We have to set aside some chairs for latecomers." Hence the guess above.

> Officials say the pace of COVID-19 vaccinations should pick up significantly in the coming weeks. For now, however, they point to a host of reasons for the lag, including vaccination systems still gearing up, federal funding that hasn't yet been disbursed to states and a requirement that states **set aside vaccine for long-term-care facilities**.

> Source:  [USAToday   Getting COVID-19 vaccine into the arms of Americans is off to a slow start; why the holdup?](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/health/2020/12/30/getting-covid-19-vaccine-into-arms-americans-off-slow-start/4087690001/)

Comment: I understand it to mean that they should reserve _some_ vaccine for the exclusive use of care facilities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Set aside* has more of a sense of keeping **some** separate. If you work in a shop, and you get a product that needs to be put on the shelves, you might *set some aside* (e.g. behind the counter) so it's not available for general sale. It's about reserving some for another purpose.

If they were talking about using the vaccine *exclusively* for these facilities, I'd expect them to use phrasing that makes that explicit. Something like *diverting all vaccine to long-term-care facilities*, or *prioritising those facilities*.

What I would say though, is that a requirement to *set aside* vaccine means that some **has** to be made available for those facilities - it's a priority. And in a situation where supplies are very limited, that could mean that **all** the vaccine ends up going there - but not because all of it is **required** to be sent there. If there's a bare minimum that needs to go to those facilities, and that amount is all that exists, they'll end up getting it all, if you see what I mean!

Answer (score 3):

The "setting aside" implies that it is for that purpose, but the exclusive part would be defined elsewhere. In this case, there are rules and regulations that are conditions of the Federal funding, and they could restrict the use of the set aside vaccine.

But the vaccine (or the chairs) set aside for one purpose could end up being used for another purpose as far as the grammar in your phrase is concerned.

Comment: Thank you.    Does "being used for another purpose" violate the rules?

Comment: I am not familiar with the rules concerning vaccine distribution, sorry. This is a site for people learning more about English, learning about US Covid-19 distribution would be on some other site.